# Question about characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius endomorphism on elliptic curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves

I have another possibly trivial question about elliptic curves. A lot of papers I've seen state that the characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius endomorphism of an elliptic curve over a finite field of characteristic $q$ is $\varphi^2-t\varphi+q$, where $t$ is the trace of the endomorphism.

Is there some simple derivation of this characteristic polynomial and if so where could I find it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Basically this is because for all $2\times2$ matrices $A$ we have
$$A^2-tr(A)A+\det A=0.$$ [Cayley-Hamilton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for that reminder I figured there was something like this going on though I can't say I see how exactly a frobenius automorphism ends up being transformed to what I assume must be matrix multiplication over the appropriate field.

Comment: The Tate module is a rank two free module over $\ell$-adic integers, and Frobenius is faithully represented by an endomorphism of the Tate module, i.e. a $2\times2$ matrix. This is also present in the study of the restriction of Frobenius to torsion groups $E[\ell]$. For example the Schoof-Elkies-Atkin algorithm seeks to calculate the trace of $\phi$ in $E[\ell]$. True, that only gives the trace modulo $\ell$, but the Chinese remainder theorem is your friend. The Tate module is a limit (characteristic zero!) of such torsion groups $E[\ell^n]$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much for the extra explanation. This will help me a lot to get a better understanding. I've been reading Silverman but the amount of time I can devote to this is limited so I've had to skim and skip a lot making many of the theorems little more then blackboxes for me. That obviously then makes it much harder to try and understand proofs later on.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you check and correct my answer ? tks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is shown in Theorem 2.3.1.(b), Chapter V, of Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves".

Comment: Hah. I did find that one but was hoping there might be a more basic proof. Though I admit the proof there is not long it does use (what to me looks like) a decent amount of firepower.

Comment: More basic? It is only using the fact that the char poly is $T^2-\text{tr} T + \det$. I don't think you can find any significantly simpler proof.

Comment: Hmm I guess I might be missing something but it seems to me it's using a representation correspondence between the Frobenius endomorphism and some endomorphism on a Tate module.

Answer (score 7):

This is explained p.117 and p.158 of [Silverman's book](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf). From what I understand :

- We have an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{F}_q$. We show that if $l$ is  a prime power coprime with $q$ then $E[l] \simeq C_{l} \times C_{l}$ is a product of two cyclic subgroups of order $l$. Thus $A \in End(E)$ acts on $E[l]$ as a $2\times 2$ modulo $l$ integer matrix $A_l = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\c & d \end{pmatrix}$ and hence $$A_l^2 - tr(A_l) A_l + \det(A_l) I  = 0, \qquad tr(A_l)=a+d, \det(A_l)=ad-bc$$
- Then we show that $\det(A_l) = deg(A) \bmod l$ and we use $tr(A_l)= 1 + \det(A_l)-\det(1-A_l)=1 + \deg(A)-\deg(1-A) \bmod l$.
- Qed. for any $l$ and hence in $End(E)$ : 
  $$A^2 - [1 + \deg(A)-\deg(1-A)] A+[\deg(A)]  = 0 $$
- When $A = \varphi$ is the Frobenius endomorphism then $\deg(\varphi) = q$ and $\deg(1-\varphi) = \#E(\mathbb{F}_q) = q+1-t$ therefore
  $$\varphi^2 - [t] \varphi+ [q] = 0$$

  and the subring of $End(E)$ generated by $[1]$ and $\varphi$ is the commutative ring $$\mathbb{Z}[\varphi] \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha], \qquad \alpha= \frac{t \pm \sqrt{t^2-4q}}{2}$$ a subring of $\mathcal{O}_K$ the ring of integers of the imaginary quadratic field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Thank you for this very complete answer! You helped me a lot!